# Condition in xsl:call-template in order to restrict considering Null or WhiteSpace for Split Scenario in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, biztalk

I need to execute a condition before calling the statement `xsl:call-template`. I am trying to check a condition where in after splitting the string if the value1 or value2 has a Null or an empty value the whole record and the element inside it should not be printed.

Here is just a short example what I need:

```
Value1 : Name1;;Name3

Value2 : Sam;Tsn;Doug
```

Expected Output :

```
<Profile>
<Type>Name1</Type>
<Value>Sam</Value>
</Profile>
<Profile>
<Type>Name3</Type>
<Value>Doug</Value>
</Profile>
```

So here the second type and value didn't print because it had a blank value in Value1
And also vice versa, if Value2 had blank value and Value1 had a value then also it should restrict it from printing it.

What I have tried :
The issue what is happening is always it contains a value so we can't do a check over there

```
<xsl:template name="WritePropertyNodeTemplateName">
<xsl:param name="Name" />
<xsl:param name="Type" />
<xsl:if test="$Name != '' and $Type != ''"> // Had put condition here but didnt work
    <xsl:call-template name="StringSplitName">
        <xsl:with-param name="val1" select="$Name" />
        <xsl:with-param name="val2" select="$Type" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="StringSplitName">
<xsl:param name="val1" />
<xsl:param name="val2" />
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($val1, ';')">
        <xsl:if test="$val2 != '' and $val1 != ''">
            <xsl:value-of select="'1st'" />
            <ns1:OtherType xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/GEP.Cumulus.WebInterfaces.BusinessEntities">
                <ns1:Name xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/GEP.Cumulus.WebInterfaces.BusinessEntities">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($val1, ';')" />
                </ns1:Name>
                <ns1:Type xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/GEP.Cumulus.WebInterfaces.BusinessEntities">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($val2, ';')" />
                </ns1:Type>
            </ns1:OtherType>
            <xsl:call-template name="StringSplitName">
                 //Tried to put condition here also but didnt work
                <xsl:with-param name="val1" select="substring-after($val1, ';')" />
                <xsl:with-param name="val2" select="substring-after($val2, ';')" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

I am using this XSLT code in BizTalk Maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do simply:

```
<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="types"/>
    <xsl:param name="values"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="';'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="type" select="substring-before(concat($types, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
        <xsl:variable name="value" select="substring-before(concat($values, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
        <xsl:if test="normalize-space($type) and normalize-space($value)">
            <Profile>
                <Type>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$type"/>
                </Type>
                <Value>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
                </Value>
            </Profile>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains($types, $delimiter)">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="types" select="substring-after($types, $delimiter)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="values" select="substring-after($values, $delimiter)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Example of call:

```
    <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
        <xsl:with-param name="types">Name1;  ;Name3</xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="values">Sam;Tsn;Doug;</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
```

Result:

```
  <Profile>
    <Type>Name1</Type>
    <Value>Sam</Value>
  </Profile>
  <Profile>
    <Type>Name3</Type>
    <Value>Doug</Value>
  </Profile>
```

---

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/93dEHFW

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this solution will work only for white space or Null condition.What about othe condition say in value2 has the value 'Tsn' and in case of the value Tsn it should not print.

Comment: @Learner I see no mention of such condition in your question, so naturally I did not address it. Anyway, it should be quite easy to add **any** condition to the existing one. If you cannot make it work, post a new question.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: I was just curious to know thats why i asked anyways Thanks for your help , Really appreciate your time for this.